# Visual Studio Extension: All items are loaded

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, envdte

I am writing a visual studio extension.  Just wondering, is there any listener event that can return true when the IDE (visual studio) is not busy, all items are loaded, or the status bar text = "Ready"?
I tried to open a file after the solution is reloaded; however, the file is opened before the studio finished deserializing (from a plug-in).
I implemented the listeners for `IVsSolutionEvents.OnAfterLoadProject`, but that's no luck.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

V

Answer (score 0):

You can also listen to [OnAfterBackgroundSolutionLoadComplete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolutionloadevents.onafterbackgroundsolutionloadcomplete).